# JavaScript - Array of Objects - Compare & Remove Duplicates ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, ecmascript-6

I have two objects:

**Object One**

```
[
  { repo: 'edat-ims-github', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'edat-ims-github-spa', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-three', status: 200 }
]
```

**Object Two**

```
[
  { repo: 'edat-ims-github', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'edat-ims-github-spa', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-one', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-two', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-three', status: 200 }
]
```

I would like to compare both arrays and remove the duplicate objects from the second array so my output looks like:

```
[
  { repo: 'test-repo-one', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-two', status: 200 }
]
```

I have tried to use ES6 to do this by running this:

```
  const result = objectTwo.filter((obj) => {
    return !objectOne.includes(obj);
  });
```

However, **result** is coming out as:

```
[
  { repo: 'edat-ims-github', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'edat-ims-github-spa', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-one', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-two', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-three', status: 200 }
]
```

Could someone please guide me on where I am going wrong and what the most optimal way of achieving this would be? In real life, both arrays have are 10000+ objects.

I am not testing equality as both arrays are not the same, I am more testing how to remove duplicates.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
obj1 = [
  { repo: 'edat-ims-github', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'edat-ims-github-spa', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-three', status: 200 }
]

obj2 = [
  { repo: 'edat-ims-github', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'edat-ims-github-spa', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-one', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-two', status: 200 },
  { repo: 'test-repo-three', status: 200 }
]

filteredArr = obj2.filter(el1 => {
  return obj1.every(el2 => {
    return !(el1.repo == el2.repo && el1.status == el2.status)
  })
})

console.log(filteredArr)
```

It starts off with checking if every element satisfies that `el1` is NOT in `el2`. If it is in `el2`, then the return statement inside the every returns a `false`, which causes the function to break off and return `false`. This means that it is removed from the filtered array `filteredArr`. However, if it is not in `el2`, then the `every` statement returns true, which means that it is included in the `filteredArr`.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you.